# Is there grep regex class that contains €

Tags: grep

Is  there specific regex class including the euro sign?
According to the [grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) the [:print:] class (AFAIK € is printable) and [:punct:] classes don't contain the euro sign as they contain only the locale (en_US.UTF-8) and ASCII punctuation characters (including $)

```
$ echo "I can has 5€ ?"  | grep -o "[[:print:]*"
I can has 5
```

Is there another solution (as I guess this problem will accouter with every currency char other than the dollar) that will allow me to catch every printable char?

**EDIT** 
After playing with putty settings, I managed to display the € when I print the file, but grep-ing it acts weird. Initially I couldn't even print the "€" bbut after changing the putty encoding to cp1252 (rather than Unicode) I can see the sign. grepping still doesn't work though

```
$ cat test.bah
I can has 5€ ?
$ cat test.bah | grep -o '[[:print:]]*'
I can has 5
 ?
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
...
```

Comment: the euro symbol is matched by the [[:print:]] class for me on gnu grep 2.6.3.  which version are you running?

Comment: 2.10 , you can see all the details on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, on my machine:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-32-virtual i686) 
grep --version grep (GNU grep) 2.10 
bash --version GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
```

The solution was to use the -P switch and match  `[[:print:]]` or non printable `[^[:print:]]` chars:

```
$ cat test.bah
I can has 5€  or 5£?
$ cat test.bah | grep -P -o '[[:print:]]*'
I can has 5
  or 5
?
```

(btw, the new lines are result of the multiple matches and not misprinting the currency signs)

```
$ cat test.bah | grep -P -o '[^[:print:]]*'
€
£
$ cat test.bah | grep -P -o '([[:print:]]|[^[:print:]])*'
I can has 5€  or 5£?
```

Few notes:

1. @melpomene showed in his answer that his console or version of grep handles the currency signs better. I am using the aws stock version of ubuntu 12.04
2. In my qustion I mentioned that I needed to change the putty settings in case
   somebody needs the settings - under Window->Translation-> set the recived data to Win1252 (Western) counter intuitive as it may seem, setting the encoeding to UTF-8 made the € and £ appear as # or  ▒ de
   pending on the drawing char selected option)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "I can has 5€ ?" | grep -o '[[:print:]]*'
I can has 5€ ?
$ echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
```

Comment: Well, it clearly doesn't work on my machine otherwise, I wouldn't bother asking. Plus, You can see from my edit (even that I mentioned it initially that my env is set to UTF8 )

Comment: Your edit doesn't show the rest of your locale settings or the encoding of `test.bah`.

Comment: 1. all the locale settings are en_US.UTF8, you reffered to "LANG" and it is shown, 2. the file encoding doen't mater the problem is the same both on ASCI and UTF-8

Comment: correction: when the file is encoded as UTF8, it shows "5â‚¬" rather and just new line

Comment: Of course the encoding matters. ASCII doesn't even have a € sign. If UTF-8 doesn't display right, it might be a problem with your putty settings.

Comment: this isn't a putty problem, as clearly (from the multiple grep matches) the grep is the one mismatching and not the console mis-displaying the correct matches

Comment: This is a putty problem, as clearly (from the multiple grep matches) grep is working fine, but your data is in the wrong encoding (and you've set putty to match that wrong encoding, so it displays as € but isn't actually processed as € by anything).

Comment: When I'm working with file saved on the server, the putty encoding settings doesn't matter, tbh, I found the problem when I checked the output of script run by cron, when  no-putty was  involved. My guess is that your bash/grep version is different

Comment: You don't have a euro symbol in that file, that's why grep doesn't match it. You only think it's a euro symbol because your (misconfigured) putty displays it as such. I'm using bash 4.1.5(1)-release and grep 2.6.3 on debian 6.0.6.

Comment: Well, I am sorry to disagree again, but as I said, the euro sign was generated by script and displayed correctly by notepad2 and the original website, and as the file wasn't generated using putty and the error occurred on background process that had nothing to do with putty, It is hard for me to believe that it is putty related, however I'm curious about this and will try to see how it works on my home PC using Ubuntu and Debian and if (when) I mange to use print to match the sign, I'll use putty to connect to that machine and report the results :)